# PHP reverse sorting sub array by keys

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, usort

Hey guys I'm trying to reverse sort a multidimensional array with usort but am messing up somewhere. Here's my code:

```
$array = array(
    array(123 => 'foo'), // duplicate
    array(124 => 'foo'),
    array(127 => 'foo'),
    array(126 => 'foo'),
    array(123 => 'foo'), // duplicate
    array(125 => 'foo'),
);

function rcmp($a, $b) {
    if($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, 'rcmp');

print_r($array);

/*
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array ( [126] => foo) )
        [1] => Array ( [125] => foo) )
        [2] => Array ( [127] => foo) )
        [3] => Array ( [123] => foo) )
        [4] => Array ( [124] => foo) )
        [5] => Array ( [123] => foo) )
    )
*/
```

I am expecting

```
/*
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array ( [127] => foo) )
        [1] => Array ( [126] => foo) )
        [2] => Array ( [125] => foo) )
        [3] => Array ( [124] => foo) )
        [4] => Array ( [123] => foo) )
        [5] => Array ( [123] => foo) )
    )
*/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I may be missing something, but it seems that you are trying to sort things that are all of the same value.

Comment: The keys are all different

Comment: So basically you want to do a `krsort` on your sub-array ? Edit : I misread your code... I get it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare on the array's indexes, you must extract the indexes in the comparison function and reverse the comparison for descending order

```
function rcmp($a, $b) {
    $a = array_keys($a);
    $b = array_keys($b);

    if($a[0] == $b[0]) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a[0] < $b[0]) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When your comparison function `rcmp` is invoked, its arguments `$a` and `$b` are arrays so your equality and less-than operators have arrays as their operands.

The equality operator on arrays works [like this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

```
TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.
```

The less-than comparison works [like this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> Array with fewer members is smaller, if key from operand 1 is not found in operand 2 then
>   arrays are uncomparable, otherwise - compare value by value.

"Uncomparable" means the comparison evaluates to `null`, which in turn causes `rcmp` to return `1`.

So what ends up happening is that when `$a` and `$b` are not identical arrays `rcmp` [always returns 1](http://ideone.com/e2aZMI) (i.e. considers that `$a` is greater). This happens irrespective of what the key in each array is, and as a result you get a meaningless ordering.

If you wanted to order these arrays by their first key with `usort`, you would do it like this:

```
function rcmp($a, $b)
{
    return key($a) - key($b);
}
```

Comment: You're right, I need to use `key()` in order to compare. Your function doesn't work though =(

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `create_function` that I came up with, accepting the best answer though. Thanks and hope this helps someone else out.
    $array = array(
        array(124 => 'foo'),
        array(123 => 'foo'), // duplicate
        array(127 => 'foo'),
        array(126 => 'foo'),
        array(123 => 'foo'), // duplicate
        array(125 => 'foo'),
    );

```
usort($array, create_function('$a, $b','return (key($a) == key($b)) 
                                                ? 0 
                                                : (key($a) < key($b)) 
                                                   ? -1 
                                                   : 1;'));

print_r($array);
```